# A positive integer $k$ such that either $kx+1$ or $kx-1$ is a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true for all integers $x \geq 2$ there exists a positive integer $k$ such that either $kx+1$ or $kx-1$ is a prime?

I checked it for $x$ up to a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any $n \in \Bbb N$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $$p \equiv 1 \pmod{n}.$$

This is a special case of [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

(There are easier proofs for the above fact, however. One can use some Galois theory to prove it. See Lecture 19 [here](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/111/101/111101001/).)

In particular, given any $n \in \Bbb N$, there exists $k$ such that $kn + 1$ is a prime. (You don't even need $kn - 1$.)

Comment: In fact since $p-1$ and $p$ never share common factors, there are also infinitely many primes such that p is -1 (mod n), so there also always exists a k such that kn-1 is prime.

Comment: Thank you very much!